# Upload file to s3 bucket using Next js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, next.js

Working on uploading file to s3 bucket using next js  getting cors error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://*****.s3-us-***.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://*****.amazonaws.com:8900' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Not getting any proper solution how to resolve this types of error
and also provided Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in s3 bucket is their any way to resolve this type of error on local machine

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

on selecting file that time need to upload file to s3 bucket below is my code of uploading

```
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "##",
    secretAccessKey: "###",
    region: "###",
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
  });
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const params = {
         Bucket: '####', // pass your bucket name
         Key: 'Zip/'+fileName, // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
         ContentType: 'application/zip',
         Body: data,
     };
     s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
         
         if (s3Err) throw s3Err
         console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
     });
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to edit the tag/title as this is probably not Next.js related. Can you try again outside of your Next.js application to confirm?

Comment: yes I tried in node js and It is working fine over their but next js it is giving CORS error

Comment: I think setting CORS is not the right solution, because you shouldn't hit a CORS issue server side in the first place as far as I understand it. Where does your code run, in a `getServerSideProps`? Can you give more details

Comment: I haven't used getServerSideProps. I used useEffect()

Comment: useEffect(() => {
      async function getItems() {
       try {
         if(val){
         
        const response = await fetch('https://######'+ val)
        const data = await response.json();
        setItems(data);
        console.log("data", data);
         }
       }catch(err) {
        console.log("useeffect error",err);
      }
    }
    getItems();
  },[val]);

Comment: That means you are running this function during client-side render, in your React code, which is not the right way and will trigger CORS error. Instead, it is meant to be called in a server-side context, either in `getServerSideProps` if you want to fetch data, or in an API route if you want to upload data (your scenario).

Comment: actually I am trying to upload file from form so whenever anyone select any file then it should get uploaded to s3 bucket, so in this case how I can implement that any idea

Comment: You need to create an API endpoint in your app, that you call on form submit. Then, this endpoint upload the file to S3. This is not really a Next.js related question at this point.